# How to add a new column in a View in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, view

I have this database in sqlite (table1):

```
+-----+-------+-------+
| _id | name  | level |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 1   | Mike  | 3     |
| 2   | John  | 2     |
| 3   | Bob   | 2     |
| 4   | David | 1     |
| 5   | Tom   | 2     |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

I want to create a view with all elements of level 2 and then to add a new column indicating the order of the row in the new table. That is, I would want this result:

```
+-------+------+
| index | name |
+-------+------+
| 1     | John |
| 2     | Bob  |
| 3     | Tom  |
+-------+------+
```

I have tried:

```
CREATE VIEW words AS SELECT _id as index, name FROM table1;
```

But then I get:

```
+-------+------+
| index | name |
+-------+------+
| 2     | John |
| 3     | Bob  |
| 5     | Tom  |
+-------+------+
```

I suppose it should be something as:

```
CREATE VIEW words AS SELECT XXXX as index, name FROM table 1;
```

What should I use instead of **`XXXX`**?

Comment: Why do you need an order column without holes?

Answer (score 2):

When ordered by `_id`, the number of rows up to and including this one is the same as the number of rows where the `_id` value is less than or equal to this row's `_id`:

```
CREATE VIEW words AS
  SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM table1 b
          WHERE level = 2
            AND b._id <= a._id) AS "index",
         name
  FROM table1 a
  WHERE level = 2;
```

(The computation itself does not actually require `ORDER BY _id` because the order of the rows does not matter when we're just counting them.)

Please note that `words` is not guaranteed to be sorted; add `ORDER BY "index"` if needed.

---

And this is, of course, not very efficient.

Answer (score -2):

You have two options. First, you could simply add a new column with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE {tableName} ADD COLUMN COLNew {type};
```

Second, and more complicatedly, but would actually put the column where you want it, would be to rename the table:

```
ALTER TABLE {tableName} RENAME TO TempOldTable;
```

Then create the new table with the missing column:

```
CREATE TABLE {tableName} (name TEXT, COLNew {type} DEFAULT {defaultValue}, qty INTEGER, rate REAL);
```

And populate it with the old data:

```
INSERT INTO {tableName} (name, qty, rate) SELECT name, qty, rate FROM TempOldTable;
```

Then delete the old table:

```
DROP TABLE TempOldTable;
```

I'd much prefer the second option, as it will allow you to completely rename everything if need be.